# how to set nswag swagger2tsclient fetch options like credentials: "include"?

Tags: typescript, nswag

Here's the commandline I use to generate my API calls:

```
nswag swagger2tsclient /input:swagger.json /output:./gen/index.ts /ExtensionCode:./base/extension.ts /ClientBaseClass:BaseClient /UseGetBaseUrlMethod:true /GenerateOptionalParameters:true
```

However, this won't generate API client with fetch including credential options I I have to manually set it.

After google for several days, I still couldn't find how to set.